# Why the results are different depending on the location of number++;?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int number = 0, step;
    while (number < 9) {

        int step = 0;
        while (step < 9) {
            step++, printf("%d * %d = %d\n", step, number, step * number);
        }
        number++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtHnt.png)

```
int main()
{
    int number = 0, step;
    while (number < 9) {
        number++;
        int step = 0;
        while (step < 9) {
            step++, printf("%d * %d = %d\n", step, number, step * number);
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4niGQ.png)

when number++ are on int step = 0, number put on to 9 but when number++ are under second while, number put on to 8. how it happened?

I think two results are same.

Comment: Are you asking why a number in output is different by one if you output it before and after incrementing it? (This might seem a little snarky, but I really get the impression that it is what you are asking and that you might not have seen it from this angle. I mean this as a constructive input.)

Comment: For clarity, you could switch the inner loop to `for(int step=1; step<9; step++)`. Don't use the comma operator just for obfuscation.

Comment: In the first code, you say something similar to "set number to 0, then print number, then increase number to 1". In the second code you say "set number to 0, then increase number to 1, then print number". When following these instructions, the printed value is different.

Comment: Dont' post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text. Program output is text.

Comment: The two versions of your code are quite different, why do you think the output should be the same?

Comment: I understand completely. thank you for every comment.

Comment: number value are same. but printed number are different. right?

Comment: Please revise question with the output as text.  Neither of the attached images show the first row printed by each program (`1 * 0 = 0` vs `1 * 1 = 1`) so question is why does number start at 0 in the first program and 1 in the 2nd.  This because in the first program `number` is incremented before the `printf()` and in the 2nd program after.

Comment: If you think that the value of `number` is the same and just the output differs then I think you did not yet get the point of output before and after increasing the value of `number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first program you print `number` before it is being incremented, and in the 2nd program you print `number` after it's being incremented.  In either case the print statements tells you want the value are of those expression at that particular point in your program.

The header file includes are part of your program.  Don't strip those out when posting a program.

Prefer `for()` to `while()` loops when you iterate over an index variable.  Here is a 3rd version where both factors start at 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for(int number = 0; number < 10; number++)
        for(int step = 0; step < 10; step++)
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n", step, number, step * number);
}
```

and example output:

```
0 * 0 = 0
1 * 0 = 0
2 * 0 = 0
3 * 0 = 0
4 * 0 = 0
5 * 0 = 0
6 * 0 = 0
7 * 0 = 0
8 * 0 = 0
9 * 0 = 0
0 * 1 = 0
1 * 1 = 1
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise. now I know number value are same. but printed number are different. I will try to use for()